# Code first migration against production database entity framework update database with web config transformations

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have this Web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mokey;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

and

Web.Release.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="AuthContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=mysql2.gear.host;database=mokey;persistsecurityinfo=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

So I have two databases, local vs production.

Now when I run `update-database` local database is updated.

How do I run `update-database` for production database, that is migrate database to latest version?

Comment: Do you have `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` enabled in your `Configuration` class? If yes, when you deploy to production it will update the production database to latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to reconsider updating your PRODUCTION database with a code deployment. That's not what EF intended and a lot of DBA's will have issues with a direct update from code.

What we do is generate a script from our migrations that the DBA runs as described here: http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

You also have to consider what your database initializer is and set it to null or migratetolatestversion in production. You could also use migrate.exe in your build server to update your database.